# What's a word that means "something that isn't upsetting"

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought it would be "unupsetting" but apparently, that's not a word.

Edit: I don't want a word like comforting, I want a word that negates an already negative word like upsetting.

Comment: How about "soothing"?  Or any other [antonym](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/upsetting) of "upsetting"?

Comment: @HotLicks - *I* like it, but OP doesn't want an antonym, but something that "negates the negative" - a chimera, probably. OP: consider editing again to allow for a word that might actually exist, which might be identified by means of thoughtful research...

Comment: Well, one could always say "non-upsetting".

Comment: Hey OP, can we get a sample sentence, please?

Comment: Unperturbing. Or comfortable?

Answer (score 1):

The best word to negate *upsetting* would be **unfazed**

> [Unfazed:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unfazed) Not disconcerted or perturbed.

Indeed it is not a direct negation, however *disconcerted* is [synonymous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/upset) with *upsetting*

However, **unfazed** would best negated *upsetting* as contextually *upsetting* is to evoke a strong and rather negative emotion, while to be **unfazed** is to have no emotion arise.

I've included a possible sentence where **unfazed** could successfully be used as the negation of *upsetting*

> For example: We thought the news be would *upsetting* him but he seems **unfazed**

Comment: Bear in mind that 'unfazed' is not a direct substitute; 'upsetting' describes the situation, but 'unfazed' describes the person reacting to it.